# IP Throttling in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, throttling, rate-limiting

I have an ASP.Net site (uses Web API 2, though that shouldn't matter) hosted in an Azure App Service.

I want to implement IP throttling to prevent too many requests coming from a single IP address (sufficiently high to allow for universities/businesses). I know that App Services have some built-in DDOS protection, but I also want to prevent against scraping, etc.

Comment: It's fairly easy to implement throttling, even across multiple web front ends, by using a Redis Cache instance. In your Global.asax.cs file, add an Application_BeginRequest method to log the timestamp of a request from an IP address. I recommend using automatic expiration to remove old entries from cache. If there are more than X entries in a given period for an IP address, return an HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this functionality is not built into either ASP.Net or Azure App Services.

Two options:

- Use [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/api-management/) - this acts as a proxy in front of the backend. Most of its functionality is targetted towards APIs which will be consumed by other developers, but this could also be used for a mobile backend, with just one API user (your app). APIM allows you to perform filtering and transformation on requests before they reach the backend, including throttling based on IP address.
- Alternatively, build this into the app itself. There are various libraries to help with this, including [this one](https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle).

If you have a strong preference for either approach, I'm interested to hear your thoughts in the comments.